# Algorithm for optimal question to answer first in a quiz given limited possibilities

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Let `m` and `n` be positive integers. Suppose there are `m` true/false questions on a quiz. It is given that the set of questions that have correct answer `true` is one of `n` given sets (assume no two are identical). Then which question should you answer first, assuming that you want to minimize the worst case number of questions you must solve to know the correct answers for all of them?

Assume that all of the inputs (`m`, `n` and one `m*n` array describing the sets) are already stored and each element can be accessed in `O(1)` time (so a very fast algorithm could be `o(mn)`).

I think that the greedy algorithm (always pick a question so that the number of remaining possibilities is as balanced as possible) does not work in general, although a counterexample would probably have to be rather large. However, it runs in `O(mn)` time, and I think it generally gives answers that are close to optimal because it almost halves the number of possibilities at each step.

Example: `m = 4`, `n = 4`, sets are `(1), (1,2,3), (1,3,4), (2,3)`. Then picking `1` requires `2` more questions, `2` requires `1` more, `3` requires `2` more, and `4` requires `2` more, so answering question `2` is the best choice and is unique.

Is there an algorithm that runs in polynomial time of `m` and `n` and finds the exact answer? If not, is there one in polynomial time that finds a nearly optimal solution? (To define nearly optimal, sort the questions in order of the number of questions required after it is answered, and find the index of the solution that the algorithm finds; if the numbers of questions required after are `3,3,4,4,4,5` then an algorithm returing a choice taking `4` more would be second place, getting score `2/6=0.33...`, and a program guaranteeing an upper bound of `c` for some small constant `c` is considered nearly optimal.) The only algorithm I could think of that guarantees finding the optimal algorithm is a DP on the set of questions not solved yet, which is obviously exponential in `m`.

Comment: "It is given that the set of questions that have correct answer true is one of n given sets." OK, but is it also given that no partial set of correct answers is given as a set? Because the latter assumption seems to be what lets you decide that  answering 2 only requires one more question.

Comment: @גלעדברקן If you solve question 2, either the answer is true or false. If it is true, then you solve problem 1, which lets you determine the correct set; if it is false, then you solve problem 3 (or 4). This is online, not offline: you can make decisions after solving some of the questions.